# LUIS entity NOT getting detected after training with same utterance

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

We have trained LUIS with same utterance for a particular intent having multiple entity. However one entity is not identified.
To improve the accuracy we have maintained a phrase list having the entity name bind to the list.

Step 1 - Adding Utterance

[image]

Step 2 - Adding Phrase List
[image]

Step 3 - Test Result
[image]

Comment: @Scuba try making sure to include more utterances that include the entity you're trying to detect. There should be AT LEAST 15 utterances. In addition, make sure the utterances are valuable in that they demonstrate different variations--whether that be with context (word order--beginning, middle, or end of utterance), or with the entity itself in word count (can the entity be 1 word? 2? 3?), and also make sure the utterances themselves vary in length

Answer (score 0):

You LUIS model seems to be lacking some training data. LUIS supports up to 500 intents and 15.000 utterances, which means you can have 30 utterances for each intent if you have a model with all the 500 intents. If that's not the case you can have more example utterances for each intent, which can help you having a more accurate model.

Regarding your usage of phrase lists, that's the first time I've seen phrase lists used in this manner. It's like your using whole utterances as phrase list items. As per the Microsoft LUIS documentation, this is how prase lists are supposed to work:

> You can add features to your LUIS app to improve its accuracy.
>   Features help LUIS by providing hints that certain words and phrases
>   are part of an app domain vocabulary.

Source: [LUIS Docs on Phrase Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-add-features)

What I understand by that, and the way I have used phrase lists is to tell LUIS which words or expressions are interchangeable, which seems to be what you are trying to do, however with full utterances. I would advice you to replace these full utterances for keywords and expressions.

Again, keep in mind that creating an intent and providing the phrase list with the expression that should be detected as an intent it's not enough for LUIS to be able to recognize it. You must label a good amount of intents before LUIS can be able to automatically identify them.